# Userscript to flag deleted posts for moderator attention with <10K reputation

Tags: support, script-request, flags

I noticed that while the system blocks you from *viewing* deleted posts unless you have moderator tools privilege, the system will not block you from flagging them. The only flag available for deleted posts is *'In need of moderator intervention.'*

I know this because if I have an already loaded tab of a post that later gets deleted, I can flag the post for moderator attention, but not as any other reason. Or if there is a review task that I reviewed, and the post is deleted, I will still be able to view the deleted post **through the review task page** but not through the actual post page, and in this case the flag option is available and I can flag for moderator attention.

I would like to be able to flag any deleted post for moderator attention without needing 10K tools. Based on my above observations a client-side script should be enough. Does anyone have a script for this?